# Determine when perforce changelist was last updated

Tags: perforce

Does perforce track the time and date at which changes were made to changelists? For example, updating the description text, or shelving different revisions of files into the changelist? And if so, **can this information be accessed using p4 command line?**

`p4 changes -t` will include information about the *creation* time of the changelist, but not the update. `p4 describe` doesn't seem to include any flags related to time. `p4 fstat` can show time information about the files in a changelist, but not the changelist itself.

Answer (score 1):

No, changelists are not versioned objects (not even in the spec depot, annoyingly).  The only ways to track changes to changelists are to go under the covers, e.g.:

- Scrape information from the journal file (this requires some understanding of Perforce's db schema)
- Add triggers on each command that might update a changelist in the ways you want to track (this requires exhaustive understanding of Perforce's command API so you don't "miss" anything that you need to trigger on).

Comment: Thanks for the response. But even if they aren't versioned at all, even a simple 'last update time' field would be useful. The journal file might be usable for that, thanks for the insight.